# Add attribute to all forms

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

I'd like to add `autocomplete="off"` to all `<form>` tag in my symfony project and I'm looking for the best way to do such.

I don't want to change all templates to change `{{form_start}}` call or manually add attribute on form object in controller, neither add listener or subscriber on each form.

I am looking for a global solution, like a service that change all forms in one call.

Comment: You may do it with a FormTypeExtension that extends the FormType I suppose. https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_form_type_extension.html

Comment: This is more for elements, I think that I will use a javascript solution.

Comment: It's for all FormTypes, using js your feature will be impossible to test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if it's the default behavior of all your forms, it's better to think about a *root* solution.
Extending type by default will do the trick

```
class FormTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    /**
     * Return the class of the type being extended.
     */
    public static function getExtendedTypes(): iterable
    {
        // return FormType::class to modify (nearly) every field in the system
        return [FormType::class];
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options): void
    {
        if (isset($view->vars['method'])) { // Make sure we're on the base form
            $view->vars['attr']['autocomplete'] = isset($view->vars['attr']['autocomplete']) ? $view->vars['attr']['autocomplete'] : "off"; // let the possibility to override for specific forms
        }
    }
}
```

you just have to use it like that

```
class DefaultController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     * @Route("/", name="home")
     */
    public function home() {

        $form1 = $this->createForm(DemoType::class, new Demo());
        $form2 = $this->createForm(DemoType::class, new Demo(), ['attr' => ['autocomplete' => "on"]]);

        return $this->render('demo.html.twig', ['form1' => $form1->createView(), 'form2' => $form2->createView()]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I get what you want to achive. `autocomplete` is an HTML attribute so it is not directly managed by symfony, as much as I know.

The fastest solution that I found is just to add the following code (below) to the base.html.twig file.

```
<script>
    $('form').attr('autocomplete','off');
</script>
```

It's going to be applied to all Forms in this page, BUT normally all the pages extend the base.html.twig, so it'll be implemented in all pages. Ah keep in mind that it's a JQuery, so of course you need to include it.

here is an example of a possible implementation:

FILE: `base.html.twig`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>

        {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}

    </head>
    <body>

        {% block body %}{% endblock %}

        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}

        // add this -------------------------------
        <script>
            $('form').attr('autocomplete','off');
        </script>
        // ----------------------------------------

    </body>
</html>
```

Check this link maybe you'll find something more useful https://www.scotsscripts.com/blog/html-css-trick-how-to-turn-off-auto-complete.html

I hope that I helped you. :-) have a nice day, Bye

Comment: That is what I did in first place, but I was looking for a better solution without using javascript. I guess there is no other option.